# como mover mi avanze de html ,css , js a react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, aplicación-web

tengo un desarrollo en html ,css y js para un trabajo de pagina web ,en el html tengo componentes boostrap ,ademas de unos formularios con validacion y ya con bases de datos con php y sql .¿la pregunta como puedo mover todo esto a react , si se puede
? (lo voy a empezar a aprender ).

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! si.. a react, a vue, a angular... donde quieras...